# Keyboard and layout handling with React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I've been trying to figure out how to properly handle layout changes after keyboard opens up (At least on Android). I'm using latest Expo.
Example of my form:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}> 
   <View style={{flex: 1}}></View> 
   <View style={{flex: 2}}> 
     <TextInput></TextInput>
     <TextInput></TextInput>
     <TextInput></TextInput>
     <TextInput></TextInput>
     <Button></Button>
   </View>
</View>
```

The problem is, when i click on any TextInput, the keyboard squishes everything thats above it and it becomes unreachable until i close the keyboard.I've already tried using:

KeyboardAvoidingView + ScrollView inside

"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" in app.json

KeyboardAwareScrollView - seems to be working, kinda, problem below

I also have a problem with "pan" setting, screen adjusts weirdly in a way that it will squish top elements when i click on a bottom TextInput, but wont when i click on a top TextInput, which breaks KeyboardAwareScrollView i guess (It adds different padding/height to  the bottom of a screen depending on where i click to open a keyboard)

Does anybody have a better solution to this problem? I want it to simply enable scroll on view (add height ?) without squishing flexboxes or changing anything in my layout.

Answer (score 1):

It's really tough to manage multiple inputs with help of the keyboard avoiding view from React Native Library.

To find the workaround for this, and fix the issues with the Multiple Inputs and Keyboard management in iOS, I have used an npm dependency known as [react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

Which really helped me in achieving my goal.

You can also try the npm dependency, I hope it will surely help you in achieving your desired outcome.

Here I am attaching the HOC component, Using which I wrap my components in which I need to manage the input and keyboard avoiding.

HOC Component :

```
import * as React from "react"
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from "react-native"
import SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view"

/**
 * Root component for screen managing safe area view and keyboard avoiding view
 */
const Root = (props) => {
  const { style, children } = props

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1 // this will fix scrollview scroll issue by passing parent view width and height to it
        }}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
          style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        >
          <View style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {children}
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Root
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it with ScrollView, as seen below.

```
<ScrollView>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
       <View style={{flex: 1}}></View> 
       <View style={{flex: 2}}> 
         <TextInput></TextInput>
         <TextInput></TextInput>
         <TextInput></TextInput>
         <TextInput></TextInput>
         <Button></Button>
       </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sadly it only works with fixed height containers. If using "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" scroll doesn't work at all, if left on default then top container will be squished