# React Native How to avoid keyboard blocking form

Tags: react-native

I am trying to avoid the keyboard over the form, according to React Native documentation, I should be using KeyboardAwareScrollView component. the instructions are fairly simple, but I cant make it work. Am I missing anything?

```
return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Options setIpt={setIpt} />
                <View style={styles.input}>
                <ShowIpt /> // form input here
                </View>
                <Button
                    title="Create"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Create"
                    onPress={() =>
                        navigation.navigate("Result", {
                            ipt: ipt,
                        })
                    }
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    margin: 10,
},
card: {
    backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2",
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: "90%",
    display: "flex",
},

input: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    height: 250,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
},
});
```

Comment: try this npm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: Check out my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70967810/keyboard-and-layout-handling-with-react-native/71014477#71014477

Comment: react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view worked, but I still not getting why KeyboardAwareScrollView doesn't, thanks anyway for the indication

Answer (score 0):

Use automaticallyAdjustContentInsets and contentContainerStyle properties and change your style like below.

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        behavior={null}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
        style={{
           backgroundColor: 'backgroundColor',
           flex: 1,
           height: '100%',
        }}
 > 
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```